# Deploying asp.net application on windows server

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I want to now what is the easiest way to deploy asp.net site to a windows server? Normally we do by uploading files through FTP client. 
But as we can checkout repository on linux server and just running "svn up" command though SSH deploys the latest changes, is there any similar way on windows?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something that is shipped with Windows or just available on Windows?

Comment: yes, I am ok with both options, if something is shipped with windows that will be great.

Comment: I just want, one click / one command deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Web deployment tool](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy) is what I use. It can be automated from the command line, and MSBuild can be used to generate deployment packages if you use a CI server. On the simplest level though it supports 1 click deploy from the toolbar in Visual Studio (probably only recommended to development servers).

Answer (score -1):

You can do nearly the same thing on Windows.

1. Use Remote Desktop Connection to
   access the server (this is the
   windows counterpart of SSH)
2. Run "svn
   up"

An SVN client doesn't ship with Windows, but the client ports from SilkSVN and CollabNet work just as well as any other.

Comment: RDC is ssh counterpart? How do you script a file upload with RDC?